# Why can Mitsuki see Shinigami?

Tags: full-moon-wo-sagashite

When Meroko and Takuto first appear to Mitsuki, they're extremely surprised that Mitsuki can see them since humans aren't supposed to be able to see Shinigami.

Is it ever explained why Mitsuki can see them?

Answer (score 4):

It's because:

> The soul of Eichi has been watching over her since he died. When Sheldan tries to take Mitsuki's soul, it's explained why Eichi is the reason why Mitsuki can see Shinigami. This is what saved Mitsuki and Takuto after they get pierced by the Mystere's scythe at the end of the series. At the end of the manga it's revealed that Eichi refused to allow Takuto to take his soul (this was Takuto's first assignment as a Shinigami) because he wanted to meet Mitsuki again (because of the promise they made to meet again when they achieved their dreams) and stays with her for 6 years until the end of the series, when he see that she is now happy and wants to live.

Comment: Hmm, I thought I remembered something like that, but the relationship between being watched over and seeing shinigami doesn't really make sense to me, lol. If that's supposed to be why then I guess I'll have to pretend to understand it.

Comment: "it's explained why ******* is the reason why Mitsuki can see Shinigami" Was this just "******* is why she can see them" and the rest is up to imagination, or was there further explanation?

Comment: I don't have the manga or anime infront of me for reference but I think they talk about how "E" is the reason she can see Shinigami near the end of the series for both mediums. When the true identity "S" aka "John" is revealed.